# Twitter Bootstrap in Drupal 7 columns not lining up in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have the Bootstrap module installed. I have made custom tpl files for the layout of my views to strip out any unnecessary divs so the structure is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="mySection">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="linkToContent">
                        <div>
                            <img src="contentImg" class="img-responsive"/>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm tearing my hair out because at 992px - 1199px in Safari, and 1200px + in Chrome my second line of columns is out. The 4th column is floating right and the 5th and 6th are floating left below the 4th like this:

```
[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] 
            [ 4 ] 
[ 5 ] [ 6 ]
```

It's fine 991px and lower in both browsers.

I had assumed there was something within the divs that was throwing out the padding or column width, or something like that as I've had problems with straight Bootstrap and HTML projects where the content of the column, despite fitting ok visually, has pushed the columns out in a similar way. So, I've stripped it right down and taken out my own CSS and most of the content, but it's actually now worse than before (it had been fine in Chrome).

I've had some success with taking the guttering off the rows but that's caused problems in other areas.

Now wondering if Bootstrap with Drupal is more trouble than it's worth and I should instead use a simple grid system like Responsive Grid System. Any advice or help would be very welcome!

Comment: Well, with the info we have right now, we can't help you at all. Give us a link to your site or post more info.

Comment: Hi brance, I'm not sure what more info I can give - that's all the HTML and there's no custom CSS. The site's in development so I can't link. I appreciate it's not much to go on but perhaps someone else out there has encountered this issue and resolved it. In the meantime I've added px to the .container class and that seems to have 'fixed' it: media (min-width: 992px) {.container{width:980px; } } and media (min-width: 1200px) {.container{width:1180px; }}

Comment: Does [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) report any errors on your page?

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when one (or some) of your columns are slightly different in vertical size. To fix this you should use the rows that bootstrap provides and enclose every 3 columns in a different row.

Comment: Thanks @Alberto, that's helpful to know. My content's dynamic so without messing around with JS maybe just setting a height on the columns would fix it. For now setting a slightly larger .container width seems to have done it with no issues caused elsewhere.